# Unrecognized option "csrf_provider" under "security.firewalls.main.form_login" despite csrf enabled

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.1

After setting up the FOSUser Bundle I have experienced this error

> Unrecognized option "csrf_provider" under "security.firewalls.main.form_login"

Now I know how to use google and the two main things that could cause the problem are

1. Not enabling the **csrf_protection** in *config.yml*
2. Not properly setting the **csrf_provider** in *security.yml*

The problem here is the fact that both of these options are properly set for me.

Here is the config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection:
        enabled: true
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/data/data.sqlite"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
```

And security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
       main:
           pattern: ^/
           form_login:
               provider: fos_userbundle
               csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
               # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
               # my syomfony is 3.1 I believe
           logout:       true
           anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I will also throw in the routing.yml which is the one from the FOS bundle setup

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

And with all that I'm still getting this issue. It's happeing upon clearing the cache in console so...clearing the cache isn't really a fix to this issue.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Replace `csrf_provider` with `csrf_token_generator` in your **`security.yml`** file, this will fix your problem!

Check this link for more information https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-4-configure-your-application-s-security-yml

Comment: Addendum: this solution is for FOSUser v2+ for Symfony2.8+

Comment: Works for Symfony 4 too